# Having a segmentation fault c++

Tags: c++

I know I'm not the best at this but I'm trying to learn. I try to compile my program and it works. I run the program but when I get to the end it says segmentation fault for dumped. I think it involves the sorting I am trying to do. It worked before I tried to sort by stealsPG. After I did that and the swap it stopped working. Any ideas why?

```
    //main.cpp

#include <string>
#include "Player.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

string response;
Player* PlaArray = new Player[5];
cout << "Time to make your basktball team!" << endl;
cout << "Press 1 to go by position and 2 if you do not care!" << endl;
cin >> response;
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("Team.txt");
ifstream inFile;
string pick1;
string pick2;
string pick3;
string pick4;
string pick5;
string player1;
string player2;
string player3;
string player4;
string player5;
string firstname;
string lastname;
string position;
string team;
string pointsPG;
string reboundsPG;
string assistsPG;
string stealsPG;
string fake;
if (response == "1")
{
    cout << "How would you like to sort your Point Guards?" << endl;
    cout << "Press 1 if you dont have a preferance, 2 for points per game(PPG), 3 for rebounds per game(RPG)," << endl;
    cout << "Press 4 for assists per game(APG), and 5 for steals per game(SPG)." << endl;
    cin >> pick1;
    if (pick1 == "1")
    {
        for(int x = 0; x<1; x++)
        {
            inFile.open("PG.txt");
            getline(inFile, position, ',');
            getline(inFile, firstname, ',');
            getline(inFile, lastname, ',');
            getline(inFile, team, ',');
            getline(inFile, pointsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, reboundsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, assistsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, stealsPG, '\n');
            PlaArray[x].setFirstname(firstname);
            PlaArray[x].setLastname(lastname);
            PlaArray[x].setPosition(position);
            PlaArray[x].setTeam(team);
            PlaArray[x].setPointsPG(pointsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setReboundsPG(reboundsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setAssistsPG(assistsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setStealsPG(stealsPG);
            if (outFile.is_open())
            {
                player1 = PlaArray[x].Report();
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Unable to Open File" << endl;
            }

        }
        inFile.close();
    }
    cout << "How would you like to sort your Shooting Guards?" << endl;
    cout << "Press 1 if you dont have a preferance, 2 for points per game(PPG), 3 for rebounds per game(RPG)," << endl;
    cout << "Press 4 for assists per game(APG), and 5 for steals per game(SPG)." << endl;
    cin >> pick2;
    if (pick2 == "1")
        {
        for(int x = 0; x<1; x++)
        {
            inFile.open("SG.txt");  
            getline(inFile, position, ',');
            getline(inFile, firstname, ',');
            getline(inFile, lastname, ',');
            getline(inFile, team, ',');
            getline(inFile, pointsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, reboundsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, assistsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, stealsPG, '\n');
            PlaArray[x].setFirstname(firstname);
            PlaArray[x].setLastname(lastname);
            PlaArray[x].setPosition(position);
            PlaArray[x].setTeam(team);
            PlaArray[x].setPointsPG(pointsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setReboundsPG(reboundsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setAssistsPG(assistsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setStealsPG(stealsPG);
            if (outFile.is_open())
                {
                    player2 = PlaArray[x].Report();
                }
            else
            {
                cout << "Unable to Open File" << endl;
            }   

            }
            }
    inFile.close();
    cout << "How would you like to sort your Small Fowards?" << endl;
    cout << "Press 1 if you dont have a preferance, 2 for points per game(PPG), 3 for rebounds per game(RPG)," << endl;
    cout << "Press 4 for assists per game(APG), and 5 for steals per game(SPG)." << endl;
    cin >> pick3;
    if (pick3 == "1")
    {
        for(int x = 0; x<1; x++)
        {
        inFile.open("SF.txt");
        getline(inFile, position, ',');
        getline(inFile, firstname, ',');
        getline(inFile, lastname, ',');
        getline(inFile, team, ',');
        getline(inFile, pointsPG, ',');
        getline(inFile, reboundsPG, ',');
        getline(inFile, assistsPG, ',');
        getline(inFile, stealsPG, '\n');
        PlaArray[x].setFirstname(firstname);
        PlaArray[x].setLastname(lastname);
        PlaArray[x].setPosition(position);
        PlaArray[x].setTeam(team);
        PlaArray[x].setPointsPG(pointsPG);
        PlaArray[x].setReboundsPG(reboundsPG);
        PlaArray[x].setAssistsPG(assistsPG);
        PlaArray[x].setStealsPG(stealsPG);
        if (outFile.is_open())
        {
            player3 = PlaArray[x].Report();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Unable to Open File" << endl;
        }

        }
        inFile.close();
    }
    cout << "How would you like to sort your Power Fowards?" << endl;
    cout << "Press 1 if you dont have a preferance, 2 for points per game(PPG), 3 for rebounds per game(RPG)," << endl;
    cout << "Press 4 for assists per game(APG), and 5 for steals per game(SPG)." << endl;
    cin >> pick4;
    if (pick4 == "1")
    {
        for(int x = 0; x<1; x++)
        {
        inFile.open("PF.txt");
        getline(inFile, position, ',');
        getline(inFile, firstname, ',');
        getline(inFile, lastname, ',');
        getline(inFile, team, ',');
        getline(inFile, pointsPG, ',');
        getline(inFile, reboundsPG, ',');
        getline(inFile, assistsPG, ',');
        getline(inFile, stealsPG, '\n');
        PlaArray[x].setFirstname(firstname);
        PlaArray[x].setLastname(lastname);
        PlaArray[x].setPosition(position);
        PlaArray[x].setTeam(team);
        PlaArray[x].setPointsPG(pointsPG);
        PlaArray[x].setReboundsPG(reboundsPG);
        PlaArray[x].setAssistsPG(assistsPG);
        PlaArray[x].setStealsPG(stealsPG);
        if (outFile.is_open())
        {
            player4 = PlaArray[x].Report();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Unable to Open File" << endl;
        }

        }
        inFile.close();
    }
    cout << "How would you like to sort your Cetners Guards?" << endl;
    cout << "Press 1 if you dont have a preferance, 2 for points per game(PPG), 3 for rebounds per game(RPG)," << endl;
    cout << "Press 4 for assists per game(APG), and 5 for steals per game(SPG)." << endl;
    cin >> pick5;
    if (pick5 == "1")
    {
        for(int x = 0; x<1; x++)
        {
            inFile.open("C.txt");
            getline(inFile, position, ',');
            getline(inFile, firstname, ',');
            getline(inFile, lastname, ',');
            getline(inFile, team, ',');
            getline(inFile, pointsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, reboundsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, assistsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, stealsPG, '\n');
            PlaArray[x].setFirstname(firstname);
            PlaArray[x].setLastname(lastname);
            PlaArray[x].setPosition(position);
            PlaArray[x].setTeam(team);
            PlaArray[x].setPointsPG(pointsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setReboundsPG(reboundsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setAssistsPG(assistsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setStealsPG(stealsPG);
    if (outFile.is_open())
    {
        player5 = PlaArray[x].Report();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to Open File" << endl;
    }

    }
    inFile.close();
    }
if (pick5 == "5");
{
    for( int x = 0; x<10; x++)
    {
        inFile.open("C.txt");
        getline(inFile, position, ',');
            getline(inFile, firstname, ',');
            getline(inFile, lastname, ',');
            getline(inFile, team, ',');
            getline(inFile, pointsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, reboundsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, assistsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, stealsPG, '\n');
            PlaArray[x].setFirstname(firstname);
            PlaArray[x].setLastname(lastname);
            PlaArray[x].setPosition(position);
            PlaArray[x].setTeam(team);
            PlaArray[x].setPointsPG(pointsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setReboundsPG(reboundsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setAssistsPG(assistsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setStealsPG(stealsPG);
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i<9; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<9; j++)
        {
            if  (PlaArray[j].getStealsPG().compare(PlaArray[j+1].getStealsPG()) >0)
            {
                swap(PlaArray[j], PlaArray[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }
    }
        for(int x = 0; x<1; x++)
        {
            getline(inFile, position, ',');
            getline(inFile, firstname, ',');
            getline(inFile, lastname, ',');
            getline(inFile, team, ',');
            getline(inFile, pointsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, reboundsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, assistsPG, ',');
            getline(inFile, stealsPG, '\n');
            PlaArray[x].setFirstname(firstname);
            PlaArray[x].setLastname(lastname);
            PlaArray[x].setPosition(position);
            PlaArray[x].setTeam(team);
            PlaArray[x].setPointsPG(pointsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setReboundsPG(reboundsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setAssistsPG(assistsPG);
            PlaArray[x].setStealsPG(stealsPG);
        if (outFile.is_open())
                {
                        player5 = PlaArray[x].Report();
                }
                else
                {
                        cout << "Unable to Open File" << endl;
                }
        }   
    inFile.close();


}
outFile.close();

    cout << player1 << endl;
    cout << player2 << endl;
    cout << player3 << endl;
    cout << player4 << endl;
    cout << player5 << endl;
}
}
void swap(int*i, int*j)
{
    int c;
    c = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = c;
}
```

Comment: it crashes, because it has terrible formatting. Just joking. Seriously: Properly format your code :P

Comment: Why didn't you make your `player` and `pick` arrays also?   You duplicate the same code 5 times over.

Comment: Im not sure why. I am new to this and not exactly sure what I'm doing. It was working fine until I tried to sort out my txt files. It printed and was working. I was trying to do it similar to a project I had to do in class but went off on my own. I know its probably not the prettiest but at this point if i could get it to work id be happy with that.

Comment: Your `swap` function is for swapping integers. You're using it to swap `Player` objects, which aren't integers. Aren't you getting a warning for the `swap(PlaArray[j], PlaArray[j+1]);` line?

Comment: @Barmar Probably `std::swap` is being called instead. That's the genius of saying `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the only problem but it's a (big!) problem.

You allocate space for 5 `Player` with

```
Player* PlaArray = new Player[5];
```

but you try to use 10 of they with

```
if (pick5 == "5");
{
    for( int x = 0; x<10; x++)
    {
        inFile.open("C.txt");
        getline(inFile, position, ',');
        getline(inFile, firstname, ',');
        getline(inFile, lastname, ',');
        getline(inFile, team, ',');
        getline(inFile, pointsPG, ',');
        getline(inFile, reboundsPG, ',');
        getline(inFile, assistsPG, ',');
        getline(inFile, stealsPG, '\n');
        PlaArray[x].setFirstname(firstname);
        PlaArray[x].setLastname(lastname);
        PlaArray[x].setPosition(position);
```

This is bad.

p.s.: and, yes: tobi303 is right: you have a terrible formatting. We are joking but the suggestion it's a good one: properly format your code.

p.p.s: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thanks that got rid of the fault!. What kind of things should i do to format better? Also it still will not swap? any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: For a better format, well, you should use a text editor that can support automatic indenting. I use `vim` but there are others. For swap, delete your function and use the standard swap (add `#include <algorithm>`, if you're using C++98, or `#include <utils>`, if you're using C++11 or C++14)